# VideoView Streaming: Audio works but video is black

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

I have a very strange issue. I am using a steam video and I play it on my app but the issue is that Audio works but video is not working. It shows a black screen (See image for reference.) I have no idea what the issue is. Audio works fine but video shows black screen.

Any ideas of what the issue can be?

Here is my code for reference:

```
public class Video_Low_Mission extends Activity {
    // Put in your Video URL here
    private String VideoURL = "rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov";
    // Declare some variables
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    VideoView videoview;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Set the layout from video_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video__low__mission);
    // Find your VideoView in your video_main.xml layout
    videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
    // Execute StreamVideo AsyncTask
    new StreamVideo().execute();

}


// StreamVideo AsyncTask
private class StreamVideo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressbar
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Video_Low_Mission.this);
        // Set progressbar title
        pDialog.setTitle("Mission TV (Low Quality)");
        // Set progressbar message
        pDialog.setMessage("Buffering...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressbar
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

        try {
            // Start the MediaController
            MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                    Video_Low_Mission.this);
            mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
            // Get the URL from String VideoURL
            Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
            videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
            videoview.setVideoURI(video);

            videoview.requestFocus();
            videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
                // Close the progress bar and play the video
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    videoview.start();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            pDialog.dismiss();

            // Error Here

            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

// Not using options menu for this tutorial
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.video__low__mission, menu);
    return true;
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/VideoView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing of mov files is not supported on the android.  mov is an apple format, and there is not a default video codec in android to play them.  [Reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

Comment: Thank you. I guess that is my issue. Will convert the stream to the formats on the documentation. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [vitamio](http://vitamio.org/vitamios?locale=en) framework, it supports .mov format. Check also this [decription](http://vitamio.org/pages/whats-vitamio?locale=en).

Comment: Thank, but how do I install it? Sorry, I am new to Eclipse and android development :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with the following code, I hope it works for you.

```
videoView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```